# Oracle SQL Developer french date format?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer and I want to have a french format of the date like: 
31-DÉC-14

I tried:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH'; 
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YY';
```

After this, when I insert a date value in a table it shows like this:

```
31-DÉC. -14
```

Can someone tell me the reason for this?

Comment: Can ou make it `NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'FMDD-MON-YY';`

Answer (score 1):

```
select to_char(add_months(TRUNC(sysdate,'YYYY'),level),'DD-MON-YY') as withoutFM, 
       to_char(add_months(TRUNC(sysdate,'YYYY'),level),'FMDD-MON-YY') as withFM
from dual
connect by level <=12
```

**RESULT:**

```
WITHOUTFM   WITHFM
01-FÉVR.-14 1-FÉVR.-14
01-MARS -14 1-MARS-14
01-AVR. -14 1-AVR.-14
01-MAI -14  1-MAI-14
01-JUIN -14 1-JUIN-14
01-JUIL.-14 1-JUIL.-14
01-AOÛT -14 1-AOÛT-14
01-SEPT.-14 1-SEPT.-14
01-OCT. -14 1-OCT.-14
01-NOV. -14 1-NOV.-14
01-DÉC. -14 1-DÉC.-14
01-JANV.-15 1-JANV.-15
```

Month has the *Maximum* of 5 characters (Eg: FÉVR.). So, while printing, in order to maintain a fixed format, Oracle loads spaces to the one lesser than the maximum possible length

So in your case it makes `DÉC.` gets converted to `DÉC.` after appending spaces.

Adding `FM` (Format Mask) to the date format eliminates it!

Comment: Thanks but its still not what I'm looking for. I want months with only three letters, no dot in it.

Comment: But the months abbreviation in French is this way only! Reference [Here](http://www.loc.gov/acq/conser/conserhold/Mosabbr.htm)

Comment: You _can't_ have only 3 letters @user2420374, otherwise June and July both render as `JUI`.

Comment: Never thought that June and July will be same, so I think my teacher made a mistake.